# How to gracefully switch between networks in WebRTC?

Tags: android, ios, webrtc

Suppose I have an established `PeerConnection` on Wifi. How to gracefully switch network to mobile without interrupting the session?

I obviously can stop everything and renegotiate the session, but I don't thing that this is the solution.

There are also `iceConnectionReceivingTimeout` and `iceBackupCandidatePairPingInterval` parameters which seems to be designed exactly for that case, but unfortunately I cannot find any hints on how to use them apart from [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/CZP8GdRHboY). Apparently just setting them does not do anything.

Comment: In fact, I think (never tried :/) that ICE has been designed for this kind of behavior. You may have a look at [ICE restart parameter](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5245#section-9.1.1.1).

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned before, You can't. However, if you are using the newest WebRTC from chromium there is a way to minimize the delay.

The fastest available option is to catch the network change event and restart the connection by recreating the `offer` in the same `RTCPeerConnection` with an `iceRestart: true` flag and sending it to the participant.

https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#dom-rtcofferoptions

This will automatically trigger the renegotiation by generating and using new values for the ICE username & password fragments - `ufrag`/`pwd`.

> **NOTE**
>
> Performing an ICE restart is recommended when iceConnectionState
> transitions to "failed". An application may additionally choose to
> listen for the iceConnectionState transition to "disconnected" and
> then use other sources of information (such as using getStats to
> measure if the number of bytes sent or received over the next couple
> of seconds increases) to determine whether an ICE restart is
> advisable.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is, you can't. The current connection will drop instantly for a start...

The signalling phase negotiates a pair of ip's and ports that are mutually accessible from both ends. This will necessarily change when you change off your wifi to the mobile network, because your IP will change, as will your firewall, routing etc. You'll need to go through that whole process again.